# Determining index of list(zip)

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to determine which tuple pair in a zip (`tax_zip`) generates the maximum of values in "welfare_levels". Really simple code to do this that I've made is below. However when I try to solve this it generates a `list index out of range` error. What is the issue with trying to index the list using the `max_welfare_index`?

```
tau_grid = np.linspace(0.0001, 1-1e-5,15)
tau_b_grid = np.linspace(0.0001, 1-1e-5,15)

welfare_levels = []

tax_zip = zip(tau_grid, tau_b_grid)

for t, tb in tax_zip:
    S = society_welfare (0.6, t, tb)     
    welfare_levels.append(S)

maximum_welfare = max(welfare_levels)
max_welfare_index = welfare_levels.index(maximum_welfare)
print(max_welfare_index)

tax_zip2= list(tax_zip)

maximizing_taxes = tax_zip2[max_welfare_index]
print(maximizing_taxes)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the problem you have.  `zip` produces an iterator.  After you finish the `for` loop, the iterator is finished.  So, `tax_zip2` receives an empty list.  You would have learned that if you had printed out intermediate values.

Fix this by converting to a list early on:

```
tax_zip = list(zip(tau_grid, tau_b_grid))
```

Now you can reuse tax_zip several times.